# how to send data with form label element?

Tags: html, forms, label

I should send data with form when submit button pressed.This value should be invisible and I used `<label name=r_id id=r_id style="visible:hidden"> 1 </div>`

This is my form

```
   <form id="send_message" action="lib/send_message.php" method="post">

    <textarea name="message" cols="45" rows="3" id="message"></textarea>
    <label  name="r_id" id="r_id" style="visible:hidden"> 1 </label>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
    <input type="reset"    name="Submit2" value="Reset">

But in my .php file It shows only message ,id is empty.
```

I used  $message= $_POST['message'] and $r_ID=$_POST['r_id'] ;

**EDIT**

I should write that this label value must be change.And I am changing it with Jquery where the mouse clicked it gets  tags id.Can I change value attribute with Jquery ?

Comment: There are a few issues with your markup, for example all input tags must be inline tags, eg. <input type="hidden" value="1" />

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're after a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="r_id" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input type="hidden"
```

are made for this and they won't appear if CSS are disabled (but of course they'll still appear in the HTML code)

Answer (score 0):

LABELs are not form elements that can hold or send data. 
They are captions tied to form elements.

`<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="r_id" id="r_id" VALUE="1"/>`

This should do what you want.