# angular 2 form submit with select tag

Tags: html, forms, angular, submit

I trying to send form with angular 2 to rest api, my problem is I want to give a select tag name the label value.

example :

this is the component.html :

```
<div class="ui raised segment">
  <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form: Sku</h2>
  <form #f="ngForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)"
        class="ui form">

    <div class="field">
      <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="skuInput"
             placeholder="SKU"
             name="sku" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="select1" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:spanish: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note1" id="select1" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

      <label for="select2" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">english: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note2" id="select2" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

      <label for="select3" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:frensh: </label>
      <select class="form-control" name="note3" id="select3" ngModel>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want the the name of **select 1** be **spanish** (value of label 1)

component.ts :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-history',
  templateUrl: './post-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-history.component.css']
})
export class PostHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log('you submitted value:', form);
  }

}
```

every thing work ok if i give every select tag a different name :

[image: every select have name, instead of that name I want to show the label value of every select]

every select have name, instead of that name I want to show the label value of every select.

Answer (score 1):

[LABELs are not form elements that can hold or send data. They are captions tied to form elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792948)

So, the label is not sent with the ngForm on submit.

Why not putting your label value as the name of the select control:

```
<label for="select1" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-2 align form-control-label">Langues:spanish: </label>
<select class="form-control" name="spanish" id="select1" ngModel>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Like this you will get the result you seek:

[image: result]

**
To address your comment, you can always keep your labels text in an array on the component like:

```
labelsName = [{select1: "your 15 words label"}, {select2: "another label"}]
```

Then, when you get your submit, you map the name of each selector with the key on your array to get the label.

Comment: thanks for your comment , I didn't like to put my label value as the same name of the select controle becausee I have other name contain more than 15 words so I saw that this thing will make some troubles on my codes and my form contain more than 40 select tag ! :/ that's why I'm trying to find other solution than yours !